# Is there a way to never exit on KeyboardInterrupt in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboardinterrupt

I'm creating sort of a interactive command line in python. I have something like this:

```
def complete_menu():
    while True:
        cmd = input('cmd> ')
        if cmd == "help":
            print('help')
        elif cmd == "?":
            print('?')
```

When the user presses CTRL-C, instead of exiting the program I'm trying to make it so that it prints "please type exit to exit" and goes back to the `while True`. I have something like this at the moment:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    try:
       main()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        print('Please use exit to exit')
        complete_menu()
```

Although this works, there is a number of issues. For one, when CTRL-C is pressed the first time, it prints out the text and works perfectly. However, the second time the user presses CTRL-C, it exists with a bunch of messy text like any other program after pressing CTRL-C. Can this be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The better way to do this is to register a signal handler:

```
import signal

def handler(signum, frame):
    print("Please use exit to exit")
    # or: just call sys.exit("goodbye")

...

def main():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, handler)  # prevent "crashing" with ctrl+C
    ...


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Now when a Ctrl+C is received in your code, instead of a `KeyboardInterrupt` exception being raised, the function `handler` will be executed.  This is a basic example, customize the code within handler to do what you want.

***Note:*** My recommendation is to *actually let the user exit with Ctrl+C*, i.e. execute any cleanup code that you might need to run and then call `sys.exit` here.  Programs that require a stronger signal to kill are annoying.

Comment: Much cleaner solution than the naive alternative of `while True` and provides flexibility of handling other low-level stuff such as Out-of-Memory reaper trying to kill the app (SIGKILL) or making a process go to sleep (SIGTSTP, SIGSTOP, SIGTTIN, SIGTTOU) or waking it up (SIGCONT).

Comment: *"My recommendation is to actually let the user exit with Ctrl+C ... Programs that require a stronger signal to kill are annoying."* -- I see your point, but it depends on the program. If OP's program calls other programs or keeps variables, exiting on Ctrl+C would be annoying, and it would be better to exit on Ctrl+D.

Comment: Yes, well, that's why it should do its cleanup on SIGINT.  If a program ignores Ctrl+C then it's a safe bet that a Ctrl+\ (SIGQUIT) may be coming soon after..   Correctly handling Ctrl+C doesn't preclude you from also supporting the Ctrl+D (EOF) usage for interactive programs.